# MNIST handwritten digit

Tags: python, algorithm, neural-network, mnist

I've tried to make a script in python able to recognize handwritten digits, using this data set: http://deeplearning.net/data/mnist/mnist.pkl.gz.

More information about this problem and about the algorithm that I'm trying to implement can be found at this link: http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html

I've implemented a classification algorithm using a perceptron for each digit.

```
import cPickle, gzip
import numpy as np

f = gzip.open('mnist.pkl.gz', 'rb')
train_set, valid_set, test_set = cPickle.load(f)
f.close()

def activation(x):
    if x > 0:
        return 1
    return 0

bias = 0.5
learningRate = 0.01

images = train_set[0]
targets = train_set[1]

weights = np.random.uniform(0,1,(10,784))
for nr in range(0,10):
    for i in range(0,49999):
        x = images[i]
        t = targets[i]
        z = np.dot(weights[nr],x) + bias
        output = activation(z)
        weights[nr] = weights[nr] + (t - output) * x * learningRate
        bias = bias + (t - output) * learningRate

images = test_set[0]
targets = test_set[1]

OK = 0

for i in range range(0, 10000):
    vec = []
    for j in range(0,10):
        vec.append(np.dot(weights[j],images[i]))
    if np.argmax(vec) == targets[i]:
        OK = OK + 1

print("The network recognized " + str(OK) +'/'+ "10000")
```

I usually recognized 10% of the digits, which means that my algorithm is doing nothing, is the same as a random algorithm.

Even dough I know that this problem is popular and I can easily find another solution on the web, I'm still asking you to help me to identify mistakes in my code.

Maybe I've initialized the values of learningRate, bias and weights wrongly.

Comment: What are you asking, specifically? Are you asking us to check the quality of your code? If so, you should probably ask for that here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @JordanSinger I'm not asking for quality of the code, I want to improve the logical part of this code, I want to obtain a higher accuracy.

Comment: A single hidden NN layer is obviously not enough for image classifications. Try to read about CNN (Convolutional Neural Network) architectures...

Comment: Where's your loss computation? Usually this is done through cross entropy loss. In order to do this your output from your network has to be a probability distribution, i.e all values are between 0 and 1 inclusive and sum to 1. Your relu activation does not do this. It looks like you subtract (t - output)? You also need to do back prop through your activation function as well.

Comment: @Kevinj22 thanks. now i know what was wrong with my logic. i needed to introduce loss computation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @Kevinj22 and the other ones, I was able to solve this problem in the end.

```
import cPickle, gzip
import numpy as np

f = gzip.open('mnist.pkl.gz', 'rb')
train_set, valid_set, test_set = cPickle.load(f)
f.close()

def activation(x):
    if x > 0:
        return 1
    return 0

learningRate = 0.01

images = train_set[0]
targets = train_set[1]

weights = np.random.uniform(0,1,(10,784))

for nr in range(0,10):
    for i in range(0,50000):
        x = images[i]
        t = targets[i]
        z = np.dot(weights[nr],x)
        output = activation(z)
        if nr == t:
            target = 1
        else:
            target = 0
        adjust = np.multiply((target - output) * learningRate, x)
        weights[nr] = np.add(weights[nr], adjust)

images = test_set[0]
targets = test_set[1]

OK = 0

for i in range(0, 10000):
    vec = []
    for j in range(0,10):
        vec.append(np.dot(weights[j],images[i]))
    if np.argmax(vec) == targets[i]:
        OK = OK + 1

print("The network recognized " + str(OK) +'/'+ "10000")
```

here is my updated code. I didn't introduce loss computation in my first attempt. I also get rid of bias because I didn't find it useful in my implementation.

I run this piece of code 10 times, with an average accuracy of 88%